# Concatenate dynamic variables in loop sentence into a SQL Server procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, concatenation, procedure

I have defined a procedure that calculates a lot of statistics, suppose that it's name is calc_stat. It's input is the name of the variable that I need to analyze. Now, in my table I have 200 distinct variables, and I want to apply the procedure calc_stat to all of them. It's obvious that it's crazy to repeat the calc_stat call 200 times, so I need a Loop.

The solution that I have found is to create a new procedure that, given the 200 names of my 200 variables, and the number of variables (200), can apply the procedure calc_stat 200 times.

I try to do something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE procedure
       @variable1 nvarchar, 
       @variable2 nvarchar, 
       @max_index int
BEGIN
     DECLARE @i int
     DECLARE @aux_variable varchar
     SET @i=1

     WHILE @i<=@max_index
       BEGIN
           SET @aux_variable='@variable'+convert(varchar(10),@i) 
           -- this returns the string '@variablei'
           -- do somethig to obtain the name of the variable????
           -- apply procedure to calculate statistics to the @variablei
           SET @Sent=''     
           SELECT   @Sent = 
              'EXEC calc_stat 'value of @aux_variable'
           EXEC(@Sent)
       END
END
```

Having the strings "variable1" and "variable2" stored in the auxiliar variable @aux_variable in each iteration, I need to define a dynamic variable whose value is the input value of @variable1 and @variable2 in each iteration.

This code works if I do it without the while and using directly the variables @variable1 and @variable2, but with more variables, I can't do that.

It must be easy, but I can't find any information about it!

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the goal? This code has no sense... It will run forever, as your WHILE condition is never reached, it will set you @aux_variable in any loop throwing away former results, it will do nothing more than add the running index to a string '@variable'. For sure this is NOT what you intend... Please explain, give sample data and expected output.

Comment: The objective is to execute:

Comment: EXEC [Lib].[dbo].[procedure] name_of_variable1, name_of_variable2, 2

Comment: Now you get a -1 from me (what is really very rare...) What do you mean by "is to execute"? Look, I spend quite a while to write many questions and hints and you do nothing else than state the EXEC-syntax?

Comment: I have a table with 200 distinct variables. I want to apply the same treatment to all of them but I don't want to repeat the code 200 times. So, with this procedure, and thw while loop of course, I can give each name of each variable and apply the same code to each variable, writing it only once.

Comment: Sorry, Shnugo, that syntax is working perfectly in my SQL Server 2008. My problem is not the syntax, it's the specific function or code that I need, to obtain the value of the dynamic variables.

Comment: I know the EXEC syntax :-) and yes, it is working normally. Your don't have a problem with EXEC but with the code inside your  procedure. And you have a problem when you try to explain your issues to someone who has no knowledge of your goals... Tried to give an answer... If I did not understand your goals, try to explain them.

Comment: What does calc_stat do?

Comment: Well, it's analyzing the correlation between the variable to analyze and a target variable to predict in the future using prediction models. It's necessary for variable's selection before modelling, because some tools don't admit more than 30 variables to use in a predictive model. So I have to select the best 30 from 200 :S

Comment: Hi, I really would like to help you, but your problem is still completely unclear. Obviously not only for me - otherwise there would've been a better answer... Please look at my first post: give sample data and expected output. In other words: State the structure of the table which contains the variable's names, some typical data rows and the corresponding EXEC statements you want to generate.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment makes me think, that it could be as simple as that:

If your variables are within a table, you can set all of them at once.

Just paste this into an empty query window and execute. Adapt to your needs...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (MyVariable VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('variable1'),('variable2'),('variable3');

SELECT * FROM @tbl;

UPDATE @tbl SET MyVariable=MyVariable + '_SomeTextToAppend';

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to my problem.

First I define a Table called VARIABLES_LIST with only 2 columns, where I list the 200 variables. so I have a table like:

```
ROWN    VARIABLES
1       variable1
2       variable2 
...     ...
```

Then, I include in the loop, into the procedure:

```
    SELECT @Variable_aux = VARIABLES
    FROM VARIABLES_LIST 
    WHERE ROWN = @i
```

So I can use @variable_aux with the value with each  @variablei. More than that, I don't have to input the names of all the variables in the main procedure.

Good to know for people that have the same problem.

Cheers!